# Mindstorms EV3 education 1.4.2 for Windows crashes when opening second project

Tags: ev3, education

The EV3 software opens the first project with no problems, but when I open a second project it crashes and terminates.
I tried to install the EV3 software on Windows 10 (MS Surface laptop i7,16GB RAM), or on Windows 7 (Thinkpad i5, 16GB RAM), but problems 
remain the same.
 
Please guide me on how to fix it. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can look in the error log file located at: "<User Profile>AppData\Local\LEGO\MINDSTORMS EV3\crashreports". Maybe there are some useful information in it. But most likely, as MindS1 said, you need to re-create the project.

Answer (score 1):

If the same project crashes your software on multiple installations, the problem is the project file itself. Sometimes files get corrupted. Unfortunately the only real solution is to recreate your project.